# How to set a particular character in string to bold using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Component.ts file I have a variable textValue = "Hello World!"; and subTextValue = "ll". and in component.html file I try to set particular character of string in "Hello World!" ----> "He**ll**o World!" to bold using the below line of code.

```
<span>{{textVal.replace(textValue , '<b>' + subTextValue  + '</b>')}}</span>
```

But, I get output as {{textVal.replace(textValue , '' + **subTextValue** + '')}}

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a pipe as below:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'bold'
})
export class BoldPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(textValue: string, subTextValue: string): string {     
     return textValue.replace(new RegExp(`(${subTextValue})`, 'gi'), '<b>$1</b>');
 }
}
```

and in HTML:

```
<span [innerHTML]="textValue | bold:subTextValue"></span>
```

This should give you:

He**ll**o World!

Answer (score 3):

You should use a pipe for this function in innerHTML (for rendering html)

```
<span [innerHTML]="textVal | markBold:subTextValue"></span>
```

In the pipe

```
transform(textVal: string, subTextValue: string): string {
    return textVal.replace(textValue , '<b>' + subTextValue  + '</b>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below code. This is the easiest way to do.

```
<span [innerHTML] = "textVal.replace(textValue , '<b>' + subTextValue  + '</b>')"></span>
```

If you want a more clean way you could create a pipe for that.

In pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'textBold'
})
export class TextBoldPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(textValue: string, subTextValue: string): string {     
     return textValue.replace(subTextValue, '<strong>' + subTextValue + '</strong>');
 }
}
```

In HTML

```
<span [innerHTML]="textValue | textBold:subTextValue"></span>
```